# Backup mysql database in multiple files in transaction

Tags: mysql, database-backups

I'd like to backup my database automatically but store each table in separate file. I've found a simple script here: http://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/1167-export-mysql-database-into-separate-files-per-table.

However problem with this is that the data could be inconsistent if the database is changed when the script is running. I basically need to run the backup in single transaction or something like that.

Any tips?

EDIT: I could dump the entire database using one mysqldump, import it into dome dummy database to create a duplicate and then I wouldn't have to worry about transactions. Is that a good or bad idea?

Comment: I'd say implement a replication server, switch that to read-only during the backup and dump from that one.

Comment: @arkascha Sadly I don't have multiple servers at my disposal. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Why can't you do that on a single system? You just have to configure that "backup mysql server" to listen to other ports...

Comment: Rather than import the dump file, I would suggest focusing on parsing and breaking up the dump file into multiple files rather than importing the whole thing back into a database.